# Convertir la fecha y hora local a string en c++

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un proyecto de la universida. Un parqueo para ser específico, ya tengo mi clase creada pero mi metodo `get` y `set` reciben string he intentado hacerlo de varias formas pero no he tenido exito.

Se me ocurrió pasarlo a string, hay alguna forma de que pueda pasar la hora y fecha a formato *string*. Lo estoy haciendo con `to_string` pero no funciona.

```
Error: no instance of overloaded function "to_string" matches the argument list--argument types are:(time_t*)

    time_t tiempoahora;
    time(&tiempoahora);
    ctime(&tiempoahora);

    cout << to_string(&tiempoahora);
```

Comment: Que es to_string? No recordaba que c++ tenga esa función. Si quieres mostrar la cadena que devuelve ctime puedes hacerlo asi: `cout << ctime(&tiempoahora);`, y si quieres un std::string puedes crearlo asi: `std::string tiempo(ctime(&tiempoahora));`

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono, to_string existe pero no se si funciona en c++ como los demas lenguajes, muchas gracias de verdad. Soy nuevo utilizando c++

Comment: @braver https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string